# Colorbox Node and template files?

Tags: nodes, theming, javascript

I have a node being pulled into a modal with overlay using [Colorbox Node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) but it's pulling in more markup and pieces of the page than I really want.

After trying to pick through some user threads on drupal.org, the only solutions I saw suggested were ones that only work for Drupal 6 and/or break when page caching is enabled.

Is there a robust way to template the output of nodes in modals in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colorbox Node creates a new display mode for each content type - that's where you can change the fields shown.

Structure -> Content Types -> 'manage display' on the content typ ein question - in the top right, select the 'Colorbox' display mode and adjust what shows and doesn't show as needed.